# fly login doesn't use GITHUB account

Tags: concourse

Im able to login to concourse successfully using
fly -t  login -c  -n  -b

when i run,

```
fly -t <target> teams -d
```

i see, `users = local:admin`

Im not able to see my github account. 
Not sure what config is to be modified

Answer (score 0):

just ensure the team names are correctly entered as they are case sensitive